# 404 not found in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

hi m trying to show a data on show.blade.php but it says 404|not found m using resource route for it. Remember m shwing the students on teacher index and from there i wants to redirect it to student/show.blade.php

StudentController:

```
  public function show(Student $student)
  {
      $data = Student::findOrFail($student->id);
      return view('student.show', compact('data'));
  }
```

teacher blade file:

```
         <td>
            @foreach($row->student as $st)
          <a href="{{ route('student.show', $row->id) }}">
             {{ $st->student_name }}</a>
            @endforeach
          </td>
```

Comment: run php artisan route:list , and check wheter route name as student.show exist or not

Comment: yes,, GET|HEAD  | student/{student} | student.show | App\Http\Controllers\StudentController@show

Comment: Why you are doing ```Student::findOrFail()```?
If you do ```function show(Student $student)``` in ```$student``` you have the student model

Comment: i found it from net i dont knw logic

Comment: If Student model doesn't exist laravel return 404.

Comment: model exists..............

Comment: in your function, after `$data = Student::findOrFail($student->id);` , what does `dd($data);` return?

Comment: in dd its returning the results https://ibb.co/9t9djsj

Answer (score 0):

you are passing id into your controller not a model so the correction is here

```
 public function show($student)
 {
  $data = Student::findOrFail($student);
  return view('student.show', compact('data'));
  }
```

and also correct this part on your blade

```
<a href="{{ route('student.show', $st->id) }}">
```

you get error not found because $student->id is returning null because you sending incorrect looping part therefore  you got error 404

Comment: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting variable    at this line 
    public function show(Student)

Comment: not Student but $student as parameter inside show, just copy my code to tried

Comment: still same issue

Comment: Trying to get property 'student_name' of non-object (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\many\resources\views\student\show.blade.php)

Comment: its already connected to show.blade , now the problem is in show.blade.php , you need to learn what's the difference between collection and array , good luck ! ,
you passed the variable to show.blade.php as $data, make sure you called without foreach and direct $data->student_name

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your route to students, but If you have a route like this:

```
Route::get('students/{id}', 'StudentController@show')->name('student.show');
```

What is the name of the array that you are passing with student collection from

TeacherContoller? $data?

If so, your blade file "teacher.blade.php" would be like this:

```
<td>
  @foreach($data as $row)
  <a href="{{ route('student.show', ['id' => $row->id]) }}">
    {{ $row->student_name }}</a>
  @endforeach
 </td>
```

Then, you would change your method to be like this:

```
/**
 * @var int $id
 */
public function show(int $id)
{
   $data = Student::findOrFail($id);

   return view('student.show', compact('data'));
}
```

Comment: Class App\Http\Controllers\Integer does not exist

Comment: sorry!! change it to "int", like this: public function show(int $id)